# How to make multiple "enemies" (i.e. squares) visible at the same time in a GUI

Tags: java, oop, paint

I'm trying to make a simple dodging game in which squares fall from the top of the screen and the player has to dodge them using the arrow keys for as long as possible.

So far it works more or less OK, but I would like to have multiple squares on-screen at the same time. In its current state, the program only paints one square at a time and then paints it again once it has run off the bottom of the window.

I apologize in advance for any structural errors or neglect of Java conventions. I have tried to make the code as readable and proper as possible, but I am still very much a beginner. I am of course open to any suggestions/corrections regarding naming conventions, structure, etc. I would greatly appreciate any tips/advice that could help me learn or point me in the right direction.

I suspect that the problem is in the paintComponent method of the Board class, or that I need to store the squares in a different kind of data structure. Or perhaps a combination of the two.

The Board class:

```java
public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private int WIDTH = 500;
    public static int HEIGHT = 500;
    public static int PLAYER_WIDTH = 25;

    private Image player;

    private int player_x = WIDTH/2;
    private int player_y = HEIGHT - 50;

    private boolean running;

    private Timer t;

    public static boolean direction_left = false;
    public static boolean direction_right = false;
    public static boolean direction_up = false;
    public static boolean direction_down = false;

    ArrayList<Square> enemy_array = new ArrayList<Square>();

    public Board() {

        addKeyListener(new DodgerListener());
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        setFocusable(true);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        ImageIcon cat = new ImageIcon("src/black_cat.png");

        player = cat.getImage();

        running = true;

        t = new Timer(50, this);
        t.start();

        manage_arraylist();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(running) {
            move_enemy();
            move_player();
            check_death();
        }
        Square.update();
        repaint();
    }

    private void move_player() {
        if (direction_left && player_x > 0)
        {
            player_x -= 5;
        }
        if (direction_right && player_x < WIDTH - PLAYER_WIDTH)
        {
            player_x += 5;
        }
        if (direction_up && player_y > 0)
        {
            player_y -= 5;
        }
        if (direction_down && player_y < HEIGHT - PLAYER_WIDTH)
        {
            player_y += 5;
        }
    }

    // makes each square fall from the top of the screen
    private void move_enemy() {
        Square.enemy_y += 10;
    }

    private void check_death() {
        if((player_x - Square.enemy_x <= Square.death_distance) && (player_x - Square.enemy_x >= -Square.death_distance) && (player_y - Square.enemy_y <= Square.death_distance) && (player_y - Square.enemy_y >= -Square.death_distance)) {
            running = false;
        }
        if(!running) {
            t.stop();
        }
    }

    // initializes the ArrayList of squares and replaces each square after it leaves the window
    private void manage_arraylist() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            enemy_array.add(i, new Square(Square.enemy_x, 0));
        }
        if(Square.enemy_y >= HEIGHT) {
            enemy_array.remove(19);
            enemy_array.add(0, new Square(Square.enemy_x, 0));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if(running) {
            g.drawImage(player, player_x, player_y, this);
            for (int i = 19; i >= 0; i--) {
                enemy_array.get(i).paint(g);
            }
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
        } else {
            Font f = new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 16);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.setFont(f);
            g.drawString("Game Over", (WIDTH/2), HEIGHT/2);
        }
    }
}
```

The Square class:

```java
public class Square {

    public static int enemy_x;
    public static int enemy_y;
    private static int square_size;
    public static double death_distance;

    public Square(int x, int y) {
        setEnemyLocation();
        setSquareSize();
        setDeathDistance();
    }

    // determines how close the player can get to each square without dying
    private static double setDeathDistance() {
        return death_distance = square_size*0.75;
    }

    private static int setSquareSize() {
        return square_size = (int) (Math.random()*100);
    }

    // determines a random x coordinate at the top of the screen for the square to be painted at
    private static void setEnemyLocation() {
        int random = (int) (Math.random()*490);
        enemy_x = random;
        enemy_y = 0;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(enemy_x, enemy_y, square_size, square_size);
    }

    // changes the x coordinate and size of the square once it falls through the bottom of the window
    public static void update() {
        if(enemy_y >= Board.HEIGHT) {
            setEnemyLocation();
            setSquareSize();
            setDeathDistance();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You only have static variables in Square. So all Squares share the same x, y, size, etc. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: Thanks! I was able to figure it out.